# SQL statement and LINQ returning different amount of data

Tags: sql, linq

I'm trying to convert a SQL statement to LINQ and for some reason the result sets I'm getting are different. The SQL is returning more data than the LINQ.

This is the SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ssLookup.StopID, 
       dc.CityName, 
       dc.StateAbbrev, 
       sc.CarrierID, 
       sc.CarrierCode, 
       sc.CarrierName 
 FROM ScheduleDestinationCache dc 
INNER JOIN ScheduleStops ssFilter ON ssFilter.CarrierID = dc.CarrierID 
INNER JOIN ScheduleStops ssLookup ON dc.CityID = ssLookup.StopID 
INNER JOIN ScheduleCarriers sc ON ssLookup.CarrierID = sc.CarrierID 
WHERE (ssFilter.StopID = 582 OR ssFilter.StopID IN 
          (SELECT * FROM dbo.GetTwins(582)))
ORDER BY dc.CityName, dc.StateAbbrev
```

This is the LINQ statement:

```
    (from sdc in ScheduleDestinationCaches
      let twins = GetTwins(582).Select(gt => gt.StopIDs)
     join ssFilter in ScheduleStops on sdc.CarrierID equals ssFilter.CarrierID
     join ssLookup in ScheduleStops on sdc.CityID equals ssLookup.CityID
     join sc in ScheduleCarriers on ssLookup.CarrierID equals sc.CarrierID
    where ssFilter.StopID == 582 || twins.Contains(ssFilter.StopID) 
  orderby sdc.CityName, sdc.StateAbbrev
   select new {
        ssLookup.StopID, 
        sdc.CityName, 
        sdc.StateAbbrev, 
        sc.CarrierID, 
        sc.CarrierCode, 
        sc.CarrierName
    }).GroupBy(g => new 
                    {
                       g.StopID, 
                       g.CityName, 
                       g.StateAbbrev, 
                       g.CarrierID, 
                       g.CarrierCode, 
                       g.CarrierName
                    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would change the SQL to:

`SELECT ssLookup.StopID, dc.CityName, dc.StateAbbrev, sc.CarrierID, sc.CarrierCode, sc.CarrierName 
FROM ScheduleDestinationCache dc 
INNER JOIN ScheduleStops ssFilter ON ssFilter.CarrierID = dc.CarrierID 
INNER JOIN ScheduleStops ssLookup ON dc.CityID = ssLookup.StopID 
INNER JOIN ScheduleCarriers sc ON ssLookup.CarrierID = sc.CarrierID 
WHERE (ssFilter.StopID = 582 OR ssFilter.StopID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.GetTwins(582))) 
GROUP BY ssLookup.StopID, dc.CityName, dc.StateAbbrev, sc.CarrierID, sc.CarrierCode, sc.CarrierName 
ORDER BY dc.CityName, dc.StateAbbrev`

Comment: Are the number of StopIds returned by the query the same as returned by the code?  Are they they same if you remove the group by from your linq?

Comment: There is a big difference. The SQL query returns more than 400 records that is correct, and the LINQ returns only 19.

Comment: @user1286550: As your LINQ query has a GROUP BY in it, and our SQL query does not, that is more than adequate to explain the difference in row counts.  **Don't confuse the ORDER BY with the much different GROUP BY clause**.

Comment: But the SQL has a Distinct.